# Interpretation of Integral of Differential 3-Form over 3-Manifold in Engineering (or Physics)?

Tags: work, tensor-calculus, gauss-law, integration

[This is a repost of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164258/interpretation-of-integral-of-differential-3-form-over-3-manifold-in-engineering and https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44539/interpretation-of-integral-of-differential-3-form-over-3-manifold-in-engineering.]

So, the standard interpretation of a differential 1-form's integral over a compact, connected, oriented 1-manifold is work, and the standard interpretation of a differential 2-form's integral over a compact, connected, oriented 2-manifold is flux, in engineering/physics parlance.

What would be an interpretation of a differential 3-form's integral over a compact, connected, oriented 3-manifold (say, a submanifold of the 6D configuration space ["c-space"] of a robot arm) in standard engineering/physics parlance?

I'm trying to motivate differential forms as the generalizations of tangent vector fields over curves and normal vector fields over surfaces in Calc III to my Calc III students, but it's difficult to motivate something without knowing its interpretation. (I only actually assign problems on 3- and higher-form integrals as Extra Credit problems, but present the notions of 0-, 1-, 2-, and 3-forms on open, connected subsets of R2
and R3, their wedge products, their exterior derivatives, and their Hodge stars as a parallel and unifying theory to the notions of functions, vector fields, cross products, and grad, curl, and div as part of the standard lecture. I also illustrate 0- and 1-forms and their Hodge stars on R to explain why there "is no" de Rham cohomology of open, connected subsets of R and why continuous 1-forms [Hodge stars of functions] therefore always have an antiderivative on compact intervals in R as part of FTC ["Exterior derivatives are always zero and points separate"].) Any actual examples of integrals of 3- (and higher-)forms in engineering/physics work to illustrate would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: In a 4D spacetime, current becomes a 3-form and can be integrated over some 3-D hypersurface, just as a current 2-form can be integrated over a 2-D surface in 3 spatial dimensions.  But that may be too many new concepts at once for your students.  If this would be of interest nonetheless, let me know and I'll try to write up a more thorough description as an answer.

Comment: I thanks you so much for the reply, but the current 3-form is kind-of the Hodge star of a 1-form in 4-space, isn't it? Of course, every 3-form is the Hodge star of something on a 3-manifold in N-space. I thank you so much, but I'm not sure that's for what I'm looking